# Discord.py collecting mgs(quotes) and displaying them in a randomly

Tags: python, discord.py

How would my discord bot collect mgs(quotes) and display a random quote.

basically I'm using >>add to add a quote to a list and >>quote to display a random quote from a list. Can anyone help with that??

```
@client.command()
async def quote(ctx):
    responses = [
    'quote 1',
    'quote 2',
    'quote 3'
]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(responses))

@client.command()
async def add(ctx):
  ctx.send("***COMING SOON***")
```

Answer (score 0):

You ideally need to have a database for purposes like this, but for demonstration purposes, we are just going to use a simple JSON file.

```py
@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):

    try:
        with open("quotes.json", "r") as r:
            j = json.load(r)
            all_quotes = j["quotes"]
    except:
        await ctx.send("No quotes stored! Add it using the quotes command")
        return

    await ctx.send(random.choice(all_quotes))


@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, quote_):
    def add_quote(quote, file="quotes.json"):
        with open(file, "r+") as fw:
            j = json.load(fw)
            j["quotes"].append(quote)
            with open(file, "w+") as wp:
                wp.write(json.dumps(j))

    try:
        with open("quotes.json", "r"):
            pass
    except:
        with open("quotes.json", "w+") as wp:
            wp.write('{"quotes" : []}')
    finally:
        add_quote(quote_)
        await ctx.send("Done!")
```

Something like this would do it. (Don't manually create a json file, it'll do it itself)

This will result in :
[image: result]

Full code :

```py
import discord
import os
import random
import json
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Sucessfully logged in as {bot.user}")


@bot.command()
async def quote(ctx):

    try:
        with open("quotes.json", "r") as r:
            j = json.load(r)
            all_quotes = j["quotes"]
    except:
        await ctx.send("No quotes stored! Add it using the quotes command")
        return

    await ctx.send(random.choice(all_quotes))


@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, quote_):
    def add_quote(quote, file="quotes.json"):
        with open(file, "r+") as fw:
            j = json.load(fw)
            j["quotes"].append(quote)
            with open(file, "w+") as wp:
                wp.write(json.dumps(j))

    try:
        with open("quotes.json", "r"):
            pass
    except:
        with open("quotes.json", "w+") as wp:
            wp.write('{"quotes" : []}')
    finally:
        add_quote(quote_)
        await ctx.send("Done!")


bot.run(os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN"))
```